# Debug not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, clone

I started editing a c# console app on my laptop in vs and pushed to a git repo. I cloned the repo to my desktop through visual studio and opened the solution, however when I try to run, it says the debug.exe cannot be found? I was under the impression solutions cloned from github should run?

Comment: Did you try to build the app before starting it? bin/debug and bin/obj folders are usually ignored during commit and push so not part of your repo

Comment: I must admit I am a newbie in vs, i have rebuild now, but my two .net core versions don't match.

Comment: What do you mean by "... my two .net core versions do not match"? Do you get any exception or compile error? Please check your project properties (right click on project -> properties) and have a look on the selected target framework.

Comment: my laptop has 3.1 desktop has 3.0, target is 3.1

Comment: Then either install 3.1 on your desktop or change the target framework (see my comment above how to find it) to 3.0

Comment: I'm installing 3.1, thanks for your help, again I apologize for my lack of knowledge in VS.